# Space before period

Tags: html, include

I am inserting ColdFusion includes within a sentence and for some strange reason I have a space appearing before the period. I know that there is not a trailing space in my include file.

```
<cfinclude template="/includes/facts/doctoral.cfm">
```

The result in the browser is:

> 1 doctoral program .

Comment: What is the content of `doctoral.cfm`?

Comment: Whitespace is a very funny thing. You can swear from here to Sunday that no such space exists but yet it very well may (depending on a variety of variables). The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to create an entirely new file and hand type the content, do NOT copy paste. Failing that, include the file contents here.

Comment: The whole sentence looks link this: ESU offers <cfinclude template="/includes/facts/undergrad.cfm">, <cfinclude template="/includes/facts/grad.cfm"> and <cfinclude template="/includes/facts/doctoral.cfm"> from which to choose. Then displays in the browser as ESU offers 55 undergraduate programs , 20 master's programs and 1 doctoral program from which to choose. In this case there is a space before the comma.

Comment: I would suggest whatever `cfoutput` or `WriteOutput` statement you're using in or around those includes is throwing out extra whitespace... either pass each output through [trim](https://cfdocs.org/trim) first, or place each include inside a [cfsavecontent](https://cfdocs.org/cfsavecontent) (essentially an output buffer) then trim the output of each one when you display it